# How can i get back smaller size icon in VS Code Editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am newbie for Visual Code Editor.I Pressed CTRL+' two times by mistake and Size of each icon becomes two times larger.How can I get back default size of icons ?

Comment: Have you tried `CTRL-`?

Comment: Thank you so much , it solved .

Comment: It can solved by view > zoom out also.

Answer (score 5):

Open VS Code Editor, and press `CTRL+-`, this will decrease the size of all icons.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In mac, it is (command and -) to decrease overall elements size in VS code.To regain press simultaneously [(command and shift) then press + ] means [command +]
> 2. In windows press (CTRL+) and (CTRL-) this will increase and decrease respectively in VS code.